# Как реализовать алгоритм бота?

Tags: python, многопоточность, opencv

Есть одна онлайн игра и я там когда-то написал скрипт на кликермане для фарма ресурсов. Но он баговал, он был палевным. А сейчас мне захотелось написать что-то адекватное и мне это поможет закрыть один предмет в универе.
Реализовать я это решил на Python. Там есть библиотеки Opencv и autogui - это то что мне нужно.

Какая должна быть логика: есть миникарта и нужно сканировать её каждую секунду. Если там появляется кто-то из других игроков, нужно выполнить другую логику(это остановка процесса фарма). Если карта чистая, то нужно запустить процесс фарма и заниматься дальше своими делами.
Как я понял, это можно решить потоками. Но я не понял как на питоне убивать потоки. И далее я почитал и запутался: эту задачу решать нужно через многопоточность или многопроцессорность?
Логика фарма: Есть отдельный поток это клик стрельбы. Есть отдельный поток сбор ресурсов. Я зациклил функции по условию флага. Но чтобы обратно запустить, я заставляю функцию вызывать саму себя. И из-за этого ломается спустя несколько минут скрипт. Слишком много рекурсий.
И я не могу понять, это я с потоками недоразобрался или есть адекватное решение задачи? Ещё сложно всё это правильно описать. У меня в голове есть задача и я её решал по этапах и в целом наверное сделал кашу и ошибки. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять как это правильно сделать и как вообще работают такого рода задачи.

https://github.com/Brodja/bot_sky2fly
main

Answer (score 0):

Потоки на питоне не убиваются нативным способом. Создавай флаги конкретно для циклов, которые работают в отдельном потоке, в случае изменения условий(пришел игрок) - меняешь флаг. Цикл останавливается.

Comment: Вот я что-то такое и пытался сделать. Я убрал вызов функции и больше не ломается. Я наверное случайно создал рекурсию ненужную.

Comment: Твой код в целом имеет много повторений ненужных и ссылок, избавляйся от избыточности похожих участков, сложно такой код воспринять.

Comment: Это я знаю, там можно 1 переменную сделать вместо 4х ссылок. Вместо 4х повторений цикл. Но пока не будет всё работать отлично, это помогает отследить где баги.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть какие-то библиотеки по типу автогуи, только чтобы курсор и клавиатура скриптом использовались в нужном мне окне (как в кликермане есть привязка к окну). Чтобы было не прямое использование курсора, а имитация.

Comment: Реализация имитации нажатия довольно замороченная тема для python. В основном используется перехват управления мыши/клавиатуры. Попробуй покопать в сторону pynput. А что на счет захвата отдельного окна - я это делал через pywin32.

Comment: Спасибо большое)